# Unix file with newlines within quotes

Tags: bash, text-processing, csv

I've got a CSV weird file with quotes within quotes and newlines and what not in one single column. Now I need to identify that column with "newlines" as one column and replace newlines with some delimiter.

I have 3 columns, the 3rd column will have some HTML text with all double quotes and each and every special character. But the double quotes are escaped with double quotes, like `"<This ""is"" string>"`.

Input:

ID, Name, text

```
"1","abc","Line 1"
"2","def","Line2
""line2"",line2"
"3","ghi","line3"
```

Output:

```
ID, Name, text
"1","abc","Line 1"
"2","def","Line2 ""line2"",line2"
"3","ghi","line3"
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no real issue with your file. It has embedded newlines and double quotes. A CSV parser would be able to handle it properly. Escaping double quotes with `"` (while double quoting the field) is the proper way to escape embedded double quotes in a CSV file.

To replace the *embedded* newlines in your CSV file with a `@` character, you could do this:

```
$ csvformat -M '@' file.csv | tr '\n@' '@\n'
1,abc,Line 1
2,def,"Line2@""line2"",line2"
3,ghi,line3
```

This uses `csvformat` from [the csvkit toolbox](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  It's a proper CSV parser that is able to reformat CSV files.

The command pipeline above first replaces all newlines that are *not* embedded with the `@` character.  Then I use `tr` to swap the remaining newlines and the `@` characters with each other, ending up with a CSV file whose embedded newlines are `@`.

This relies on the fact that the original data in the file contains no `@` characters.

If you then want to have spaces instead of a marker of where the newlines originally were, then use `tr '\n@' ' \n'` instead of the `tr` shown above:

```
$ csvformat -M '@' file.csv | tr '\n@' ' \n'
1,abc,Line 1
2,def,"Line2 ""line2"",line2"
3,ghi,line3
```

Note that this would make it extremely difficult to re-insert the original newlines if there are *other* spaces in the data (as there is in the third field on the first line).

Would you prefer that `csvformat` did not remove all unnecessary double quotes, then use it with `-U 1`:

```
$ csvformat -U 1 -M '@' file.csv | tr '\n@' ' \n'
"1","abc","Line 1"
"2","def","Line2 ""line2"",line2"
"3","ghi","line3"
```

---

Simpler answer (October 2022) using Miller:

```bash
$ cat file
ID,Name,text
"1","abc","Line 1"
"2","def","Line2
""line2"",line2"
"3","ghi","line3"
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$text = gsub($text,"\n"," ")' file
ID,Name,text
1,abc,Line 1
2,def,"Line2 ""line2"",line2"
3,ghi,line3
```

This reads the CSV file (which is assumed to have a normal header) and uses `gsub()` to replace any newlines in the `text` field with spaces.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated !!! but we do not have the 'csvformat' utility in our server.

Comment: @Kumar you can easily install it

Answer (score 1):

You can try with sed :

```
sed '
  :A
  2,$ {
    /[^"]\"$/! {
      N
      bA
    }
    s/\n//g
  }
' infile
```

Catch on each line from 2 to end if last char is "
If not, get a newline and restart the loop.
At the end of loop, remove each "\n".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the GNU version of `sed`, making use of the extended regex support, as shown:

**Command-line:**

```
$ sed -Ee '
   1b
   /^("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$/!{
      N;s/\n/ /;s/^/\n/;D
   }
' input.csv
```

**Results:**

```
ID,Name,Text
"1","abc","Line 1"
"2","def","Line2 ""line2"",line2"
"3","ghi","line3"
```

**Explanation:**

- `-E` turns on the extended regex mode.
- `1b` will take the header to stdout as it is.
- `/^("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$/` will match a line that is fully balanced w.r.t double quotes.
- Hence when we negate it we get our unbalanced lines, IOW, we need to seek their closing double quotes in the succeeding line(s).
- We read in the next line and append to pattern space, `N`, and remove the newline.
- We repeat this process till the pattern space is balanced.

With `POSIX` `sed` you would need to change the above somewhat:

```
$ sed -e '
   1b
   /^\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*$/b
   N;s/\n/ /;H;s/.*//;x;D
' input.csv
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, you must be that Indian Super hero travelled into space !! Thanks for the explanation too , very much helpful

Comment: Naah...you are you !! Champion stuff!!

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -MText::CSV -e 'my $csv=Text::CSV.new;  .perl.put for $csv.getline_all(open($*ARGFILES, :r, :!chomp));'
```

Sample Input:

```
ID, Name, text
"1","abc","Line 1"
"2","def","Line2
""line2"",line2"
"3","ghi","line3"
```

Sample Output:

```
$["ID", "Name", "text"]
$["1", "abc", "Line 1"]
$["2", "def", "Line2\n\"line2\",line2"]
$["3", "ghi", "line3"]
```

You can handle quotes and embedded newlines using and the Raku programming language and a dedicated module (e.g. `Text::CSV`). To visualize the `\n` character I've added a call to `.perl` (FYI, `.raku`  also works). Add a mapping into the fields to change embedded newlines to underscores (additional code, below):

```
raku -MText::CSV -e 'my $csv=Text::CSV.new;  .put for $csv.getline_all(open($*ARGFILES, :r, :!chomp)).map(*.subst("\n","_", :g));'
```

Updated Output (1):

```
ID Name text
1 abc Line 1
2 def Line2_"line2",line2
3 ghi line3
```

It's really not clear from the OP's initial posting whether "doubled" double-quotes are desired (or not). Simply adding back the call `.perl` to the code above gives escaped double-quotes (below), which may be more desirable:

Updated Output (2):

```
"ID Name text"
"1 abc Line 1"
"2 def Line2_\"line2\",line2"
"3 ghi line3"
```

https://modules.raku.org/dist/Text::CSV:cpan:HMBRAND
https://github.com/Tux/CSV
https://raku.org